# Symfony default project permission error on windows

Tags: symfony, local

I'm currently working through a [Symfony tutorial book](https://symfony.com/doc/6.2/the-fast-track/en/3-zero.html)

I've gotten to the launching of a local server section and run into a problem. Whenever I go to visit the page locally I'm greeted with;

`Warning: file_put_contents(C:\Users\***/var/cache/dev/annotations.map): Failed to open stream: Permission denied`

The *** being there to shorten the file path (it is correct).

I've looked for solutions but they all use things like chown and such that I don't have access to on windows, I did check my file permissions and the entire project repo has "full access" to the system user, I'm a little stumped.